# Set ngStyle using the value of a complex object in a ngFor - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to set the width of an html element that is defined in a `ngFor` loop, using a variable from the collection being iterated. My code below does not give me an error but it appears I am doing something wrong. Is this an acceptable way to set width, and if so what and I doing wrong here?

```
export class ColumnValue {
    value: string;
    width: string;
}

export class GridHeader {
    values: Array<ColumnValue> = new Array();
}

export class GridData {
    headers: Array<GridHeader> = new Array();
}
```

Markup

```
<div *ngFor="let header of gridData.headers">
  <div *ngFor="let value of header.values">
     <div class="gridHeader" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'value.width' }" > 
        {{value.value}}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The width is not set and when I inspect the element, I see the [object Object]

```
<div _ngcontent-apy-c9="" class="gridHeader" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]">Column Header Text 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I removed the quotes around the variable being referenced in ngStyle.

Changed

```
<div class="gridHeader" [ngStyle]="{'width': 'value.width' }" >
```

To

```
<div class="gridHeader" [ngStyle]="{'width': value.width }" >
```